# Description item label as part of a sentence

Tags: spacing, lists, description

Are description lists appropriate for definitions where the item label is part of a sentence?

```
\begin{description}
\item[Apples] are members of the Rosaceae family.
\item[Pineapples] are the only economically important Bromeliad fruit.
\item[Bananas] are delicious.
\item[Blending] of the above fruits into smoothies is possible.
\end{description}
```

Is it more appropriate to have inter-word spaces between item labels and the rest of the sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this would be up to personal preference. As such, here's a way to obtain either:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[Apples] are members of the Rosaceae family.
  \item[Pineapples] are the only economically important Bromeliad fruit.
  \item[Bananas] are delicious.
  \item[Blending] of the above fruits into smoothies is possible.
\end{description}

\begin{description}[labelsep=.3333em]
  \item[Apples] are members of the Rosaceae family.
  \item[Pineapples] are the only economically important Bromeliad fruit.
  \item[Bananas] are delicious.
  \item[Blending] of the above fruits into smoothies is possible.
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

In the normal font, a space has width `.3333em`, while the default gap between the label and the subsequent description is `.5em`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\textbf{Fruit} & \textbf{Description}\\
\hline
  Apples &Are members of the Rosaceae family\\
  Pineapples& Are the only economically important Bromeliad fruit\\
  Bananas& Are delicious\\
  Blending& Of the above fruits into smoothies is possible\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{50mm}

\begin{tabular}{l|l}
\textbf{Fruit} & \textbf{Description}\\
  Apples &Are members of the Rosaceae family\\
  Pineapples& Are the only economically important Bromeliad fruit\\
  Bananas& Are delicious\\
  Blending& Of the above fruits into smoothies is possible\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{50mm}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\textbf{Fruit} & \textbf{Description}\\
  Apples &Are members of the Rosaceae family\\
  Pineapples& Are the only economically important Bromeliad fruit\\
  Bananas& Are delicious\\
  Blending& Of the above fruits into smoothies is possible\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Of course, you can always have the best of both worlds, by using, say, `\textbf` for the items on the first column and nothing else for the second one (looks somewhat like the answer provided by Werner, just mine is justified):

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \textbf{Apples} & Are members of the Rosaceae family\\
  \textbf{Pineapples} & Are the only economically important Bromeliad fruit\\
  \textbf{Bananas} & Are delicious\\
  \textbf{Blending} & Of the above fruits into smoothies is possible\\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]